# vue-sidebar-menu plug in Expanded and push the content

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just implemented a side-bar-menu using https://yaminncco.github.io/vue-sidebar-menu/#/props and what I want is a sidebar menu that pushes its content when it is expanding. Does anybody know what props or what styling should I add to create that?

This is my Vue code:

```html
<template>
    <div id="panel">
        <sidebar-menu :collapsed="collapsed" :menu="menu" :theme="selectedTheme" :show-one-child="true"
        @collapse="onCollapse"
        @itemClick="onItemClick" ></sidebar-menu>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      menu: [
        {
          header: true,
          title: 'Main Navigation',
          hiddenOnCollapse: true
        },
        {
          title: 'User',
          icon: 'fa fa-user',
          child: [
            {
              href: '/panel/group_user_list',
              title: 'Group User'
            },
            {
              href: '/panel/user_list',
              title: 'User List'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: 'Banner',
          icon: 'fa fa-flag',
          href: '/panel/banner'
        },
        {
          title: 'Subscriber',
          icon: 'fa fa-envelope',
          href: '/panel/subscriber'
        },
        {
          title: 'Recipe',
          icon: 'fa fa-list',
          child: [
            {
              href: '/panel/recipe_community',
              title: 'by Community'
            },
            {
              href: '/panel/recipe_tiarapot',
              title: 'by Tiarapot'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: 'Pers',
          icon: 'fa fa-headset',
          href: '/panel/pers'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  props: {
    relative: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I already tried to add position `fixed` and `absolute` on the menu tag, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain in detail that what exactly you want?

Comment: i want to use this plug in, but when i implement it somehow the content not pushed when the sidebar expanded @EjilarasanJ

Comment: Please show your efforts and codes about implementing it and show an image or reference something about what behavior do you expect and what is not working exactly . That makes it much easier to get your own answer

Comment: done sir, im sorry if my post offend you @MohammadMomeni

Comment: Could you reference an example that is your ideal form of a sidebar because I did not understand what you want exactly yet

Comment: so when my sidebar expanding from left to right my content is goes below my side bar, what i want is to make my side bar push the content to the right everytime it expand from left to right

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite sidebar title transition properties .
Here's some properties that I define for `left-to-right` sidebar title appearance

`yourcomponent.vue`

```html
<style>
.fade-animation-enter-active {
  transition: transform 0.15s, opacity 0.45s !important;
}
.fade-animation-enter , .fade-animation-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(-60%) !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```

**Note** `fade-animation` class is the transition class for the sidebar titles

#### [Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/side-bar-menu-test-sbyl6?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: sir, what i want is to make my sidebar push the router view (content) when it expanded, my current problem is that the sidebar go above the router view(the content)